# Bash script - unable to replace string with double quotes and curly braces

Tags: json, bash, shell, escaping, quoting

I'm struggling for some time and I would need some help with the following operation.

I have a JSON file and I would like to replace a string with something a bit more complex.

This is a snippet of my json file:

```
{ "AWS679f53fac002430cb0da5b7982bd22872D164C4C": {
   "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
   "Properties": {
    "Code": {
     "S3Bucket": "hnb659fds-assets-xxccddff",
     "S3Key": "68b4ffa1c39cb3733535725f85311791c09eab53b7ab8efa5152e68f8abdb005.zip"
    },
    "Role": {
     "Fn::GetAtt": [
      "AWS679f53fac002430cb0da5b7982bd2287ServiceRoleC1EA0FF2",
      "Arn"
     ]
    },
    "Handler": "index.handler",
    "Runtime": "nodejs12.x",
    "Timeout": 120
   },
   "DependsOn": [
    "AWS679f53fac002430cb0da5b7982bd2287ServiceRoleC1EA0FF2"
   ],
   "Metadata": {
    "aws:cdk:path": "CODE/AWS679f53fac002430cb0da5b7982bd2287/Resource",
    "aws:asset:path": "asset.68b4ffa1c39cb3733535725f85311791c09eab53b7ab8efa5152e68f8abdb005",
    "aws:asset:is-bundled": false,
    "aws:asset:property": "Code"
   }
  }
}
```

What I need is to replace this part

```
 "S3Bucket": "hnb659fds-assets-xxccddff",
```

and have the following result

```
"S3Bucket": {"Fn::Sub": "AAA-${AWS::Region}" },
```

I don't know the `AWS679f53fac002430cb0da5b7982bd22872D164C4C`. It is generated randomly and the string to replace is present several times in my json file.

The initial values to be replaced is stored in a variable along with the new value to be used in the replaced version as following:

```
cdk_bucket_name=hnb659fds-assets-xxccddff
OUTPUT_BUCKET=AAA
```

I need these variables because this is part of a bigger script

So I tried some sed but does not work

```
new_bucket_name="{"Fn::Sub\": \"$OUTPUT_BUCKET-${AWS::Region}\" }"

sed -i "s#$cdk_bucket_name#$new_bucket_name#g" my.template.json
```

One issue that I have is that `${AWS::Region}` gets interpreted so is empty.
And second, I cannot manage the quotes in order to have my desired result.

Comment: Your initial text does not look like valid JSON at all. The acute problem is that you failed to backslash the double quote before `Fn::Sub`, but please [edit] to clarify either by fixing your input, or explaining how it's correct and representative in this context. For actual JSON processing, a JSON-aware tool like `jq` would be much easier and less error-prone to use.

Comment: Indeed, I put only a snipped of my json, but I only need to replace this value, the json content is not important. The thing is that I cannot use jq because I don't know the path to the value to be replaced. And the value to be replaced is found several times in my json. Or maybe I can use jq...

Comment: I added a snippet of my json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ output_bucket=AAA
$ new_bucket_name="{\"Fn::Sub\": \"$output_bucket-\${AWS::Region}\" }"
$ cdk_bucket_name=hnb659fds-assets-xxccddff
$ sed s"/\"$cdk_bucket_name\"/$new_bucket_name/" input_file
{ "AWS679f53fac002430cb0da5b7982bd22872D164C4C": {
   "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
   "Properties": {
    "Code": {
     "S3Bucket": {"Fn::Sub": "AAA-${AWS::Region}" },
     "S3Key": "68b4ffa1c39cb3733535725f85311791c09eab53b7ab8efa5152e68f8abdb005.zip"
    },
    "Role": {
     "Fn::GetAtt": [
      "AWS679f53fac002430cb0da5b7982bd2287ServiceRoleC1EA0FF2",
      "Arn"
     ]
    },
    "Handler": "index.handler",
    "Runtime": "nodejs12.x",
    "Timeout": 120
   },
   "DependsOn": [
    "AWS679f53fac002430cb0da5b7982bd2287ServiceRoleC1EA0FF2"
   ],
   "Metadata": {
    "aws:cdk:path": "CODE/AWS679f53fac002430cb0da5b7982bd2287/Resource",
    "aws:asset:path": "asset.68b4ffa1c39cb3733535725f85311791c09eab53b7ab8efa5152e68f8abdb005",
    "aws:asset:is-bundled": false,
    "aws:asset:property": "Code"
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Pehaps explain what you changed, i.e. the missing backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Using a proper JSON parser shell tool like `jq`:

```bash
jq '
(
  .[].Properties.Code.S3Bucket |
    select(. == "hnb659fds-assets-xxccddff")
) = $newS3Bucket
' input_file.json \
  --argjson newS3Bucket '{"Fn::Sub":"AAA-${AWS::Region}"}'
```